# nested dictionary from nested lister as follow (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

Been struggling with this issue, so I hope I get some help

taken the following lister:

```
Buildings = ['nr1','nr2','n3']
offices = [1,3,2]
area=[23,[67,77,94],[78,79]]
price=[45,[43,89,56],[54,53]]
employees=[56,[45,54,78],[56,89]]

I would like to create following dictionary

{
    {'build nr1':
        { 'office 1': 
                    {'area' : '23 kvm',
                    'price' : 45
                    'employees' : 56}
        }
    }
    {'build nr2':
        { 'office 1': 
                    {'area' : '67 kvm',
                    'price ': 43
                    'employees' : 45}
        }
        { 'office 2': 
                    {'area' : '77 kvm',
                    'price' : 89
                    'employees' : 54}
        }
        { 'office 3': 
                    {'area' : '94 kvm',
                    'price' : 56
                    'employees' : 78}
        }
    }
    {'build nr3':
        { 'office 1': 
                    {'area' : '78 kvm',
                    'price' : 54
                    employees : 56}
        }
        { 'office 2': 
                    {'area' : '79 kvm',
                    'price' : 53
                    'employees' : 89}
        }
    }
}
```

**Main** goal
is create a dataframe with most probably with sub-columns.

like "Buildings nr" as index, "area", "price" and  "employes" as columns , and local 1,2,3 sub-columns depending if the building on the index has 3 or less/more offices ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
import json


Buildings = ['nr1','nr2','nr3']
offices = [1,3,2]
area=[23,[67,77,94],[78,79]]
price=[45,[43,89,56],[54,53]]
employees=[56,[45,54,78],[56,89]]

myDict = dict()

for building, office in zip(Buildings, offices):
    myDict[f"Build {building}"] = dict()
    for i in range(office):
        myDict[f"Build {building}"][f"office {i+1}"] = dict()

i = 0
for ar in area:
    i += 1
    j = 0
    if isinstance(ar, int):
        myDict[f"Build nr{i}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["area"] = f"{ar} kvm"
    if isinstance(ar, list):
        for element in ar:
            myDict[f"Build nr{i}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["area"] = f"{element} kvm"
            j += 1
k = 0
for pr in price:
    k += 1
    j = 0
    if isinstance(pr, int):
        myDict[f"Build nr{k}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["price"] = pr
    if isinstance(pr, list):
        for element in pr:
            myDict[f"Build nr{k}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["price"] = element
            j += 1
l = 0
for emp in employees:
    l += 1
    j = 0
    if isinstance(emp, int):
        myDict[f"Build nr{l}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["employees"] = emp
    if isinstance(emp, list):
        for element in emp:
            myDict[f"Build nr{l}"][f"office {j + 1}"]["employees"] = element
            j += 1

print(json.dumps(myDict, indent = 4))
```

which prints:

```
{
    "Build nr1": {
        "office 1": {
            "area": "23 kvm",
            "price": 45,
            "employees": 56
        }
    },
    "Build nr2": {
        "office 1": {
            "area": "67 kvm",
            "price": 43,
            "employees": 45
        },
        "office 2": {
            "area": "77 kvm",
            "price": 89,
            "employees": 54
        },
        "office 3": {
            "area": "94 kvm",
            "price": 56,
            "employees": 78
        }
    },
    "Build nr3": {
        "office 1": {
            "area": "78 kvm",
            "price": 54,
            "employees": 56
        },
        "office 2": {
            "area": "79 kvm",
            "price": 53,
            "employees": 89
        }
    }
}
```